# Python: Conditionally Create New Column Based on Two Other Columns (including negative values)

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements, min, absolute

Currently I have the data frame below.  The first two columns are what I have...and I want to create the third column ('Value_2_Replaced).

[image]

Essentially, if Value_1 is a positive number, then I want to compare Value_1 with Value_2 and the one with smaller value gets placed in third column.

The tricky part is when Value_2 is negative.  If Value_2 is negative but greater than Value_1, I want Value_2_Replaced to equal Value_1 but retain its negative value.

Below is the code I have tried but it does not account for the negative Value_2 situation.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
df["Value_2_Replaced"] = df[["Value_1", "Value_2"]].min(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might multiply the sign of `Value_2` with the absolute min of columns `Value_1` and `Value_2`:

```
df["Value_2_Replaced"] = pd.np.sign(df.Value_2) * df[["Value_1", "Value_2"]].abs().min(1)

df
#Account  Value_1   Value_2   Value_2_Replaced
#0     A      100       200             100
#1     B      200       400             200
#2     C      300      -400            -300
#3     D      700      -800            -700
```

Comment: Appears to have worked!  Didn't realize you could call out the sign of a column like that...brilliant :)  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

check the absolute value of your colums `abs()`

```
import pandas as pd

a = {"account":(1, 2), "col1":(100, 700), "col2":(200, -800)}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)

def col2_replaced(df):
    if (abs(df['col1'] < abs(df['col2']))) and df['col2'] < 0:
        return -df['col1']
    elif (abs(df['col1'] < abs(df['col2']))) and df['col2'] > 0:
        return df['col1']
    else:
        return df['col2']

df['col2_replaced'] = df.apply(col2_replaced, axis=1)
```

[dataframe before running function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXpoz.png)

[dataframe after running function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcUfl.png)

This is an example i put together in jupyter notebook.

The function checks the absolute value of the two columns in question and compares them. Then when the function is called it creates a new column resulting in the output you were looking for in your example screen shot